# Выравнивание элементов внутри QGridLayout, Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qss, qlayout

Пытаюсь создать нужный мне интерфейс посредством *Qt Designer*.

Проблема состоит в том, что элементы (`QLabel`, `QLineEdit`), помещенные в `QGridLayout`, выравниваются по левому краю.

Можно ли их как-то центрировать?

Скрин для наглядности прилагается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

upd: В итоге должно получиться что-то вроде этого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У QLabel и QLineEdit есть параметр SizePolicy - установите значение по-горизонтали в Expanding

Comment: Ситуация не изменилась

Comment: опубликуйте модуль `.ui`

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com.ua/ru/AC3a

Comment: ну QGridLayout это же не таблица, там imho нет центрирования, обычно задают свойства так, чтобы виджет в ячейке расширялся от края до края

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Вопрос был в том, чтобы центрировать поля ввода и лейблы (у которых четко задан размер - **`60`**) в рамках отведенного им места внутри QGridLayout (**`90`**). 
> Таким же образом должны вести себя желтые виджеты, которые имеют размер **`80`**. Это также позволит расположить поля ввода по центру относительно виджетов. 
> Для наглядности добавлю рисунок в вопрос.

Я попробовал реализовать написанное вами в своем коде. Если это то что вам надо, попробуете перенести эту логику в *Qt Designer*.

Я добавил некоторый Style Sheet для наглядности.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Frame(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 25))


class ManinWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
   
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget) 

        # widgetTop
        self.widgetTop = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widgetTop.setObjectName("widgetTop")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("pushButton", self.widgetTop)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 80))
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widgetTop)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)


# widgetCenter        
        self.widgetCenter = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widgetCenter.setObjectName("widgetCenter")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widgetCenter)

        self.frame_00 = Frame()
        self.frame_00.setObjectName("frame_00")
        self.label_00 = QtWidgets.QLabel('00', self.widgetCenter)
        self.label_00.setObjectName("label_00")
        self.frame_00.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_00, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.frame_01 = Frame()
        self.frame_01.setObjectName("frame_01")        
        self.label_01 = QtWidgets.QLabel('0-1', self.widgetCenter, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_01.setObjectName("label_01")
        self.label_01.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 20))
        self.frame_01.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_01, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)        
        self.frame_02 = Frame()
        self.frame_02.setObjectName("frame_02")         
        self.label_02 = QtWidgets.QLabel('0-2', self.widgetCenter, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_02.setObjectName("label_02")
        self.label_02.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 20))
        self.frame_02.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_02) 
        self.frame_03 = Frame()
        self.frame_03.setObjectName("frame_03") 
        self.label_03 = QtWidgets.QLabel('0-3', self.widgetCenter, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_03.setObjectName("label_03")
        self.label_03.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 20))
        self.frame_03.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_03) 
        self.frame_04 = Frame()
        self.frame_04.setObjectName("frame_04") 
        self.label_04 = QtWidgets.QLabel('0-4', self.widgetCenter, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_04.setObjectName("label_04")
        self.label_04.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 20))
        self.frame_04.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_04) 
        self.frame_05 = Frame()
        self.frame_05.setObjectName("frame_05") 
        self.label_05 = QtWidgets.QLabel('0-5', self.widgetCenter, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_05.setObjectName("label_05")
        self.label_05.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 20))
        self.frame_05.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_05) 

        self.frame_10 = Frame()
        self.frame_10.setObjectName("frame_10") 
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel('1-0', self.widgetCenter, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.frame_10.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_10) 
        self.frame_11 = Frame()
        self.frame_11.setObjectName("frame_11")         
        self.lineEdit_11 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_11.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 16777215))
        self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")        
        self.frame_11.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_11)         
        self.frame_12 = Frame()
        self.frame_12.setObjectName("frame_12")         
        self.lineEdit_12 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_12.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 16777215))
        self.lineEdit_12.setObjectName("lineEdit_12")        
        self.frame_12.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_12)   
        self.frame_13 = Frame()
        self.frame_13.setObjectName("frame_13")         
        self.lineEdit_13 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_13.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 16777215))
        self.lineEdit_13.setObjectName("lineEdit_13")        
        self.frame_13.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_13)
        self.frame_14 = Frame()
        self.frame_14.setObjectName("frame_14")         
        self.lineEdit_14 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_14.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 16777215))
        self.lineEdit_14.setObjectName("lineEdit_14")        
        self.frame_14.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_14)
        self.frame_15 = Frame()
        self.frame_15.setObjectName("frame_15")         
        self.lineEdit_15 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_15.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 16777215))
        self.lineEdit_15.setObjectName("lineEdit_15")        
        self.frame_15.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_15)

        self.frame_20 = Frame()
        self.frame_20.setObjectName("frame_20") 
        self.label_20 = QtWidgets.QLabel('2-0', self.widgetCenter, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_20.setObjectName("label_20")
        self.frame_20.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_20) 
        self.frame_21 = Frame()
        self.frame_21.setObjectName("frame_21")         
        self.lineEdit_21 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_21.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 16777215))
        self.lineEdit_21.setObjectName("lineEdit_21")        
        self.frame_21.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_21)         
        self.frame_22 = Frame()
        self.frame_22.setObjectName("frame_22")         
        self.lineEdit_22 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_22.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 16777215))
        self.lineEdit_22.setObjectName("lineEdit_22")        
        self.frame_22.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_22)   
        self.frame_23 = Frame()
        self.frame_23.setObjectName("frame_23")         
        self.lineEdit_23 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_23.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 16777215))
        self.lineEdit_23.setObjectName("lineEdit_23")        
        self.frame_23.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_23)
        self.frame_24 = Frame()
        self.frame_24.setObjectName("frame_24")         
        self.lineEdit_24 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_24.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 16777215))
        self.lineEdit_24.setObjectName("lineEdit_24")        
        self.frame_24.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_24)
        self.frame_25 = Frame()
        self.frame_25.setObjectName("frame_25")         
        self.lineEdit_25 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_25.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 16777215))
        self.lineEdit_25.setObjectName("lineEdit_25")        
        self.frame_25.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_25)        
        
        # ...  еще строка

        self.frame_50 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widgetCenter)
        self.frame_50.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 25))
        self.frame_50.setObjectName("frame_50")

        self.frame_60 = Frame()
        self.frame_60.setObjectName("frame_60") 
        self.label_60 = QtWidgets.QLabel('6-0', self.widgetCenter, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_60.setObjectName("label_60")
        self.frame_60.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_60)         
        self.frame_61 = QtWidgets.QFrame(objectName="frame_61")
        self.frame_61.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 25))
        self.frame_62 = QtWidgets.QFrame(objectName="frame_62")
        self.frame_62.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 25))        
        self.frame_63 = QtWidgets.QFrame(objectName="frame_63")
        self.frame_63.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 25))        
        self.frame_64 = QtWidgets.QFrame(objectName="frame_64")
        self.frame_64.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 25))          
        self.frame_65 = QtWidgets.QFrame(objectName="frame_65")
        self.frame_65.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 25))          
         
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_00, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_01, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_02, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_03, 1, 4, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_04, 1, 5, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_05, 1, 6, 1, 1)        

        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_10, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_11, 2, 2, 1, 1)        
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_12, 2, 3, 1, 1) 
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_13, 2, 4, 1, 1)        
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_14, 2, 5, 1, 1)        
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_15, 2, 6, 1, 1)

        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_20, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_21, 3, 2, 1, 1)        
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_22, 3, 3, 1, 1) 
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_23, 3, 4, 1, 1)        
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_24, 3, 5, 1, 1)        
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_25, 3, 6, 1, 1)
        # ...   еще строка 4
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_50, 5, 1, 1, 7)

        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_60, 6, 1, 1, 1)
# ---------------------------------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_61, 6, 2, 1, 1, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_62, 6, 3, 1, 1, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_63, 6, 4, 1, 1, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_64, 6, 5, 1, 1, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_65, 6, 6, 1, 1, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)        

# !!! +++        
        self.gridLayout_3.setColumnStretch(0, 1) 
        self.gridLayout_3.setColumnStretch(8, 1)          
        self.gridLayout_3.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3.setRowStretch(8, 1)        

        # widgetBottom
        self.widgetBottom = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widgetBottom.setObjectName("widgetBottom")        
        self.frameBottomLeft = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widgetBottom)
        self.frameBottomLeft.setObjectName("frameBottomLeft")
        self.frameBottomRight = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widgetBottom)
        self.frameBottomRight.setObjectName("frameBottomRight")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widgetBottom)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frameBottomLeft)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frameBottomRight)
        self.labelBottomLeft = QtWidgets.QLabel('labelBottomLeft', self.frameBottomLeft)
        self.labelBottomLeft.setObjectName("labelBottomLeft")
        self.labelBottomLeft.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.verticalLayoutBottomLeft = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frameBottomLeft) 
        self.verticalLayoutBottomLeft.addWidget(self.labelBottomLeft)
  
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.widgetTop, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.widgetCenter, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.widgetBottom, 1)


style = '''
#centralwidget {
    background-color: #EEC373;
}

#widgetTop, #widgetCenter, #widgetBottom {
    background-color: #876445;
}

#pushButton {
    background-color: #CA965C;
    border-radius: 40px;
    color: #fff;
}
#pushButton:hover {
    background-color: #F4DFBA;
    color: #876445;
}

#frameBottomLeft {
    border-radius:  20%;
    background-color: #CA965C;
}
#frameBottomRight {
    background-color: #876445;
}

#labelBottomLeft {
    background-color: #CA965C;
    color: #876445;
    font-size: 22px;
}

#frame_01, #frame_02, #frame_11 {
    background-color: #2F3A8F;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#label_01, #label_02, #label_03, #label_04,
#label_05, #label_10  {
    background-color: #CCD1E4;
    color: #541212;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#label_20, #label_60 {
    color: #FFBD35;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#frame_50 {
    background-color: #3FA796;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#frame_61, #frame_62, #frame_63, #frame_64,
#frame_65 {
    background-color: #FFBD35;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
'''
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("Fusion"))
    app.setStyleSheet(style)                     # +++
    
    w = ManinWindow()
    w.resize(800, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это действительно оно, спасибо!

Comment: @u_1nn пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Я видимо не совсем понял что вы хотите сделать и как вы это делали.

Предложу вам попробовать свои фантазии на увиденную вашу форму, попробуйте.

**q1416735.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>786</width>
    <height>474</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Maximum">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>80</width>
           <height>80</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>80</width>
           <height>80</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background-color: #EEC373;
    border-radius: 40px;
}</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
         <property name="autoDefault">
          <bool>true</bool>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_2" native="true">
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
       <item row="5" column="0" colspan="7">
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
         <property name="enabled">
          <bool>true</bool>
         </property>
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>0</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(116, 255, 57);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_00">
         <property name="text">
          <string/>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="6" column="0">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_60">
         <property name="text">
          <string>60</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="5">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_04">
         <property name="text">
          <string>04</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="4" column="0">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_40">
         <property name="text">
          <string>40</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="6">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_05">
         <property name="text">
          <string>05</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="0">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_25">
         <property name="text">
          <string>1</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_24">
         <property name="text">
          <string>10</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="3" column="0">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_30">
         <property name="text">
          <string>30</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="4">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_03">
         <property name="text">
          <string>03</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="3">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_02">
         <property name="text">
          <string>02</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="2">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_01">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>01</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="2">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_26"/>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="3">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_27"/>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="4">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_28"/>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="5">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_29"/>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="6">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_30"/>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="2">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_31"/>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="3">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_32"/>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="4">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_33"/>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="5">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_34"/>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="6">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_35"/>
       </item>
       <item row="3" column="2">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_36"/>
       </item>
       <item row="3" column="3">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_37"/>
       </item>
       <item row="3" column="4">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_38"/>
       </item>
       <item row="3" column="5">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_39"/>
       </item>
       <item row="3" column="6">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_40"/>
       </item>
       <item row="4" column="2">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_41"/>
       </item>
       <item row="4" column="3">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_42"/>
       </item>
       <item row="4" column="4">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_43"/>
       </item>
       <item row="4" column="5">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_44"/>
       </item>
       <item row="4" column="6">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_45"/>
       </item>
       <item row="6" column="2">
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>0</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="6" column="3">
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_4">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>0</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 255, 127);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="6" column="4">
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_5">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>0</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 255, 127);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="6" column="5">
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_6">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>0</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 255, 127);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="6" column="6">
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_7">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>0</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 255, 127);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_3" native="true">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_23">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>300</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QLabel {
    background-color: #EEC373;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>TextLabel</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос был в том, чтобы центрировать поля ввода и лейблы (у которых четко задан размер - 60) в рамках отведенного им места внутри QGridLayout (90). Таким же образом должны вести себя желтые виджеты, которые имеют размер 80. Это также позволит расположить поля ввода по центру относительно виджетов. Для наглядности добавлю рисунок в вопрос